# Mask image does not appear on the screen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have imported to the library two images and have given them the custom class names MaskImage and MaskedImage. Then i write the code:

`package
{
    import flash.display.*;`

```
public class MaskDemo extends Sprite
{
    // Properties

    private var sprMaskedImage:Sprite;
    private var sprMaskImage:Sprite;
    private var bmMaskedImage:Bitmap;
    private var bmMaskImage:Bitmap;

    // Constructor

    public function MaskDemo()
    {
        do_magic();
    }

    // Methods
    private function do_magic():void
    {
        bmMaskedImage = new Bitmap(new MaskedImage(0, 0));
        bmMaskImage = new Bitmap(new MaskImage(0, 0));

        sprMaskedImage = new Sprite();
        sprMaskedImage.addChild(bmMaskedImage);

        sprMaskImage = new Sprite();
        sprMaskImage.addChild(bmMaskImage);

        sprMaskedImage.mask = sprMaskImage;
        this.addChild(sprMaskImage);
    }
}
```

}

But it does not appear anything on the display. Any ideas why is happening that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely positive I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to just use one image to mask the other?

One thing I am seeing is that sprMaskedImage is not added to the display list. try doing `addChild(sprMaskedImage);`

Comment: I have two images and i want to mask the one with the other. So i instantiate the images from the library and put each to a sprite. Then i set the mask property of the first image to the second sprite and i add it to the display list. But when i test it does not work, i mean the mask does not appears on the screen.

Comment: Oops! Actually, i use wrong concepts to produce the desired result. Please delete this thread.